# Replace view if no ads is shown - AdMob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've an application which uses AdMob as advertisement. And every time no ads is shown it's just a "view" with nothing inside it. I am now looking to replace the empty space and add an image. Is this possible?

So, how can I replace my "view" if no ads is shown, and add an image inside it?

I've tried to googling around, but could not find anything about this.

```
//Request Advertisement
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

//Set up advertisement
advertisementBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-7225493999040026/4779408290"

advertisementBanner.rootViewController = self
advertisementBanner.delegate = self
advertisementBanner.load(request)
```

The current result is: If no ads is available there will be just an empty space in the view. I wanna replace this empty space with an image.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on admob but isn't there a delegate method... something like `adDidFailToLoad` that you can use? or just use an image as the background image of the view, which when an ad is shown will replace it

Comment: As our friend points, GADBannerViewDelegate seems to have this method: didFailToReceiveAdWithError. You should probably take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **GADBannerViewDelegate** to do this

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
}

func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
            didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    cnstAddViewHeight.constant = 0.0 // you can hide your view or replace with image here
}
```